# Invoke webharvest function from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, webharvest

I have created a webharvest function. I am able to invoke the function using webharvest code. My challenge is, need to invoke that webharvest function from a JavaScript function. Is it possible? For example, consider this:

**Webharvest method**

```
 <function name="testing">  
   <script>
   // <![CDATA[
       // code block    
   // ]]>
   </script>
```

**JavaScript method**

```
<script>
  // <![CDATA[
  function jMethod(){
    testing(); // need to call that web harvest method here
  }
  // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Try not to confuse Java with Java*Script*.

Comment: its web harvest code. In web harvest , we need to write java code within <script> tag